# Disable Auto Redirct in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

Am trying to disable HTTP auto redirect in camel,i have implemented the below code in SpringRouteBuilder ,
Problem is when am getting the HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently ,its automatically redirected.
below i added the snippet ,please let me know how to proceed.

```
  onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).process(exchange -> {
        final Exception t = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
        if (t instanceof HttpOperationFailedException) {

            LOGGER.error("HttpOperationFailedException Problem::::{}",
                    ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(t, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE));
        }
    });
 from(SOURCE_URI).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "[Service Route:][Request log:] ${body}").routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, Builder.constant("GET")).process(exchange -> {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(EMPTY_REQUEST);
            }).streamCaching().recipientList(header("PartnerUrl"));
}
```

In the below document mentioned that http://camel.apache.org/http4
Response code is in the range 300..399, Camel regards it as a redirection response and will throw a HttpOperationFailedException with the information.
am expecting this exception ,but no exception occurred and redirected.

Comment: Some of the HTTP components allow to follow redirects automatic, which you may need to turn on.

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen ,i have seen the code in http method redirector. for GET method by default followRedirects is true.could you please suggest how to off this one.